# When I'm using this query

Tags: mysql

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT e.Emp_name,
                     s.Product_Name, 
                     COUNT(*) AS employee_count, 
                     SUM(s.sales_amount) AS sales_amount, 
                     RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(s.sales_amount) DESC)rnk 
              FROM sales_emp e 
              INNER JOIN sales_sum1 s ON e.empid = s.empid 
              GROUP BY e.Emp_name,
                       s.Product_Name ) 
SELECT Emp_name,Product_Name, employee_count, sales_amount 
FROM cte 
WHERE rnk <= 15;
```

in emp name 2times showing .i want emp in single name with product name, sales amount. emp purchase 2 items emp name ,product name total amount. for example the above table have emp name babu. with babu name along with product details and total sum i want

Comment: It seems that you need in one more CTE which will enumerate rows partitioning by Emp_name and then select only 1st row for each group.

Comment: if you don't mind how to write a code can you plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need in

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT e.Emp_name,
                s.Product_Name, 
                COUNT(*) AS employee_count, 
                SUM(s.sales_amount) AS sales_amount, 
                -- enumerate products per employee ordering by total sale
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_name ORDER BY SUM(s.sales_amount) DESC) rn 
         FROM sales_emp e 
         INNER JOIN sales_sum1 s ON e.empid = s.empid 
         GROUP BY e.Emp_name,
                  s.Product_Name )
SELECT Emp_name,
       Product_Name, 
       employee_count, 
       sales_amount 
FROM cte  
-- select one product with maximal sale per employee
WHERE rn = 1
-- select 15 employees with maximal sale per product
ORDER BY sales_amount DESC LIMIT 15;
```